# data can't enter database (php, sql)

Tags: php, html, sql

hye, I has a code and I try to enter it to database

```
/*example data
  $areaSes = Area 1
  $row['area'] = Area 2;
*/

$area = $areaSes . ',' . $row['area'] ;
echo 'output :' . $area; 

//output
//output : Area 1 , Area 2
```

but then, in the database, only value Area 1 is enter, but value 2 didn't
why it become like that?

//full code

```
$plugins1 = '';
if(!empty($_POST['checkboxvar'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkboxvar'] as $plugins) {


        $plugins;

        $sql="SELECT * FROM reportevidence where id='$plugins'";
        $result_set=mysql_query($sql);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
        {
            //$area = $areaSes . ',' . $row['area'] ;

            $area = "".$areaSes.",".$row['area']."";


        }

        echo "output:".$area."";  // output: Area 1, Area 2

        $queryPass = mysql_query("update reportevidence set usedByArea='$area' where id = '$plugins' ",$conn);


        //$plugins1 .= $plugins.":";
}}
```

database
[image of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCKDi.jpg)

i want it to be 
Area 1, Area 2

Comment: there is no code in your question for inserting or updating a db, your question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're looping through a row are you trying to concatenate the string?

try

```
$area .= $areaSes . ',' . $row['area'] ;
echo 'output :' . $area;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$area = "".$areaSes.",".$row['area']."";
echo "output:".$area."";
```

Comment: still can't enter the 2nd data. It only enter "Area1," without anything behind ","